# Spring Boot + Mysql + TransactionManager

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, transactions, spring-transactions, autocommit

I want to manage the mysql transactions by my own using `PlatformTransactionManager` and `@Transactional` but it doesn't work.On other hand,when i work on oracle database it work effectively as per my requirement but in mysql unable to control transactions.
Also turn off the mysql autocommit default setting to zero but still face that problem.

Comment: post your code..

Comment: MySQL make sure you are using a table type that actually supports transactions. MyISAM isn't transactional use InnoDB.

Comment: Here is the code          /*@Transactional*/
 public int insertIntoGmat(String message){            TransactionStatus statusT = utility.getTransaction().getTransaction(utility.getTransactionDef());
int status=0;              status=utility.getJdbcTemplate().update("insert into table(fields) values(?,?)",new Object[]{"Value"});
status=status=utility.getJdbcTemplate().update("insert into table(fields) values(?,?)",new Object[]{"Value"});
    utility.getTransaction().rollback(statusT);
    System.out.println("Status ["+status+"]");
    return status;} Same Code work using Oracle

Comment: Hey guys I found the solution,I change the mysql engine from MyISAM to InnoDB.Now its work fine.For more detail about mysql engine follow the link :- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-engines.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I found the solution,I change the mysql engine from MyISAM to InnoDB.Now its work fine.For more detail about mysql engine follow the link :-

> [dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-engines.html](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-engines.html)